# How to convert follow path to object

Tags: path

How to convert follow path to object I have made a add object constraint follow path and given the path. I dont want to animated it. I want that mesh to be used. How can i delete the path and used the mesh that is created. An image i have attached with the follow path i have made the sphere a shape and i dont want that path just the sphere i want with that path shape. I want to convert to a single object. ctrl+j not working and if i delete the path ever thing disappear[image]

blend file ... [image]

Comment: which modifier may i know can u plz make it clear in brief

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all your meshes, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to open the Apply menu, select Visual Transform. This will apply the constraints, but you still need to remove them (they're applied AND active) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
Then you can join them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In object mode press "**alt+c**"[image]